# PHP count the same ids in the same array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a array (table `post_tracking`) :

```
$postList = PostTracking::select('post_id', 'post_type', 'created_at')->whereDate('created_at', '2021-09-11')->get()->toArray();
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 93
            [post_type] => 2
            [created_at] => '2021-09-11 02:11:12'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 93
            [post_type] => 2
            [created_at] => '2021-09-11 05:10:12'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 93
            [post_type] => 3
            [created_at] => '2021-09-11 12:01:02'
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 94
            [post_type] => 4
            [created_at] => '2021-09-11 14:09:30'
        )
     [4] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 93
            [post_type] => 2
            [created_at] => '2021-09-11 16:12:20'
        )
)
```

Now i want to process this array counting by `post_id` and `post_type`.

Now I want to have the result like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 93
                [post_type] => 2
                [created_at] => '2021-09-11'
                [total] => 3
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 93
                [post_type] => 3
                [created_at] => '2021-09-11'
                [total] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 94
                [post_type] => 4
                [created_at] => '2021-09-11'
                [total] => 1
            )
    )
```

Give me any ideas.Thank you.

Comment: @PersianMan How would that count by post_id and post_type?

Comment: "_Give me any ideas._" Iterate over the array and count by post_id and post_type. ;) What have you got so far?

Comment: use @Pasha answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in your query, no need to write additional code. Try to experiment with this:

```
->select('post_id', 'post_type', 'created_at', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->groupBy('post_id', 'post_type')
```

Comment: Group by `post_id` twice?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. A perfect answer